# PHP ZipArchive File URL (Http)

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

So i have a script that downloads files into a zip file. But it is not working. It was brought to my attention that you cannot use ziparchive with files on external url. But then i found a blog post on stack that said we can. I tried the solution but i am still getting an empty or currupt zip file.

The solution they recommended was this

```
    // Download file
    $file = "http://url.com/file.pdf";        
    $ch = curl_init($file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $file_content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Add to zip
    $zip->addFromString($fname, $file_content);
```

Im running the code in a loop to add all the files to the zip. But im still getting an empty/corrupt zip file. Can anyone help me get a external files (http) added to a zip and downloaded? Thanks you.

Comment: Try debugging the script. First try only adding one 1 to the zip instead of looping. Make sure the contents of the file you get from your curl look correct etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this be easiest?

```
$pdf = file_get_contents('http://url.com/file.pdf');
$zip->addFromString($fileName, $pdf);
```

Comment: I tried that but my php files are still corrupt? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211149/php-loop-download-file-to-desktop-files-corrupt

Comment: link not found?